# How to use `small button` class within `input-group` class in Foundation CSS

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I need to group the button and I need it as a small button.

I can get small button alone using `button small` class.

But when I try to get button group with a small class, I am not getting a small button.

How to achieve `input-group` with `small button`

**Official Doc**: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/forms.html

**Codepen**: https://codepen.io/ZURBFoundation/pen/rmdRqg?editors=1000

**My Code**:

```
<div class="small-3 column">
      <div class="float-right">
        <div class="input-group search-button">
          <input type="text" class="input-group-field">
          <div class="input-group-button">
            <a href="#" class="small button" >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Screenshot**:
[image]

Comment: Are you using float, flex or XY grid please?

Comment: I'm using float grid @dom_ahdigital and `Version 6.3.0`

Comment: And do you have a screenshot of what exactly the alignment and size of the button should be?

Comment: screenshot added bro @dom_ahdigital